# Problem with convert String to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

When I run this I get exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-12-15 13:48:52' could not be parsed: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values

I write to console:  2020-12-15 13:48:52

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Podaj datę:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();


        if (input.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")) {
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dateTimeFormatter1);
            printDateTime(localDateTime);
        } else if (input.matches("\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")) {
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime localDateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dateTimeFormatter2);
            printDateTime(localDateTime2);
        } else if (input.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            LocalDateTime localDateTime3 = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dateTimeFormatter3);
            printDateTime(localDateTime3);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Zły format");
        }
    }

    private static void printDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        System.out.println("Czas lokalny: " + ZonedDateTime.now());
        System.out.println("UTC: " + ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC")));
        System.out.println("Londyn: " + ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("London")));
        System.out.println("Los Angeles: " + ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("Los Angeles")));
        System.out.println("Sydney: " + ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("Sydney")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use HH instead of hh. Also, London is not a valid ZondId

Comment: Alternatively: `LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-12-15 13:48:52".replace( " " , "T" ) )`  Replace the SPACE in middle with a `T` to comply with standard ISO 8601 formats used by default in *java.time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DateTime pattern in your [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) causes the problem you see here. You need to use `HH` instead of `hh`

- `hh`:  This is an hour-of-day pattern that uses a 12 hour clock, with AM/PM indications.
- `HH`:  This is an hour-of-day pattern that uses a 24 hour clock. Takes input between 0-23

Sidenote, the zones you use seem to be invalid.
The corresponding zones would be

```
Europe/London
America/Los_Angeles
Australia/Sydney
```

Answer (score 2):

For this requirement, do not use regex because it makes your program unnecessarily complex and error-prone. You can use the optional patterns in square brackets with `DateTimeFormatter`. Apart from this,

1. Use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) to append a default value for a field  (e.g. `HOUR_OF_DAY`) to the formatter for use in parsing.
2. Use [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) to return a copy of this date-time with a different time-zone, retaining the instant.
3. Use the standard naming convention (Region/City) of timezone e.g. `Europe/London`.
4. Use `HH` instead of `hh` for `HOUR_OF_DAY` (i.e. time in 24-hour format). The symbol, `hh` is used with `a` which specifies `am/pm` (i.e. time in 12-hour format).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("[uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss][dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss][uuuu-MM-dd]")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        System.out.print("Podaj datę:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
        System.out.println(localDateTime);

        printDateTime(LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf));
    }

    private static void printDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        // Default timezone
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        ZonedDateTime zdtDefaultTimeZone = localDateTime.atZone(zoneId);

        System.out
                .println("Date-time at " + zoneId + ": " + zdtDefaultTimeZone);
        System.out.println("At UTC: " + zdtDefaultTimeZone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")));
        System.out.println("In London: " + zdtDefaultTimeZone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")));
        System.out
                .println("In Los Angeles: " + zdtDefaultTimeZone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")));
        System.out.println("In Sydney: " + zdtDefaultTimeZone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney")));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Podaj datę:2020-02-23 10:15:20
2020-02-23T10:15:20
Date-time at Europe/London: 2020-02-23T10:15:20Z[Europe/London]
At UTC: 2020-02-23T10:15:20Z[Etc/UTC]
In London: 2020-02-23T10:15:20Z[Europe/London]
In Los Angeles: 2020-02-23T02:15:20-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
In Sydney: 2020-02-23T21:15:20+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Podaj datę:23.02.2020 10:15:20
2020-02-23T10:15:20
Date-time at Europe/London: 2020-02-23T10:15:20Z[Europe/London]
At UTC: 2020-02-23T10:15:20Z[Etc/UTC]
In London: 2020-02-23T10:15:20Z[Europe/London]
In Los Angeles: 2020-02-23T02:15:20-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
In Sydney: 2020-02-23T21:15:20+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Podaj datę:2020-02-23
2020-02-23T00:00
Date-time at Europe/London: 2020-02-23T00:00Z[Europe/London]
At UTC: 2020-02-23T00:00Z[Etc/UTC]
In London: 2020-02-23T00:00Z[Europe/London]
In Los Angeles: 2020-02-22T16:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
In Sydney: 2020-02-23T11:00+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.